# How to communicate two USB slave devices

Tags: usb, gsm, lte

I have a GSM LTE evaluation board which contains a USB slave device port and a evaluation board for microcontroller which also contains USB slave device. 
I want to send commands to GSM module using the controller boards through USB.

After browsing couple of hours on internet i didn't find anything helpful.

My question is that is there any possible way to communicate two USB slave device??

Any help is appreciated...

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two USB devices cannot communicate directly one to another. Unless they support OTG. In most cases it is needed USB host controller between those two USB devices to provide some kind of link between them.